# Умножать цену на количество через js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

На странице товара есть попап окно.

Когда увеличиваешь кол-во товара цена товара увеличивается.

**Вопрос:** как это реализовать пересчет цены при увеличении\уменьшении количества товара на странице с помощью javascript?

Мои наработки:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div style="margin: 0 auto;">
  <p style="font-size: 20px;">Цена: 100 руб/м</p>
  <div class="stepper stepper--style-1 js-spinner"> <input autofocus type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" id="of_colvo" class="stepper__input">
    <div class="stepper__controls"> <button type="button" spinner-button="up">+</button> <button type="button" spinner-button="down">−</button> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Умножать цену на количество.

Comment: можете в примере показать?

Comment: <div style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <p style="font-size: 20px;">Цена:  100 руб/м</p>
    <div class="stepper stepper--style-1 js-spinner">
     <input autofocus type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" id="of_colvo" class="stepper__input">
     <div class="stepper__controls">
      <button type="button" spinner-button="up">+</button>
      <button type="button" spinner-button="down">−</button>
     </div>
    </div>                                     
   </div>

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=js+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2

Comment: мне нужен код чтобы сумму умножить на кол-во товара, без корзины)

Comment: https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/xmwxex пример с jquery

Comment: спасибо большое)